# In Odoo 14, In a Search View, A field added to filter a search, only accepts numbers, I need to use a word

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I have inherited the search view "product.product_template_search_view" and added a field to filter the available products.
This works if I type a number in the search box, but it doesn´t when trying it with words, I want it to work when I type "available" as just as it did in Odoo-10.
Is this posible?

This is the code I used:

```
    <record id="product_search_ventas_plus" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product.template.search.heredado</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_search_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='attribute_line_ids']" position="after"> 
               <field name="qty_available" string="Available Products" filter_domain="[('qty_available','&gt;',0)]"/> 
        </xpath> 
    </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: qty_available is float field  and you can type only number.You can't type word.

Comment: you can define a search field, a field with search attribut you will find plenty of examples